# Extraction of integers and characters from String

Tags: java, expression, extract

I am solving mathematical expression problem using Stack Data Structure and I get stuck at extracting numbers and math signs from the string. What I want to do is to make a program to evaluate a given expression.

My question is, how to extract all numbers and signs from string into new string array?

```
Input: 12*1*145*2+8*1*1+2*3+2+4
```

The new string array should be:

```
String[] expArray={"12","*","1","*","145","*","2","+","8","*","1","*","1","+","2","*","3","+","2","+","4"}
```

I tried with `nextInt()`, `split()`, `next()`, `nextByte()` but it was unsuccessful. Don't worry about anything else. I just mentioned the problem just to be clear on what I am talking about.

UPDATE: I don't need solution with building integers like `array[i]*10+array[i+1]` or something similar. What I need is more optimal solution.

Comment: Please leave @MichaelLihs's edit in place, it is perfectly good.

Comment: Flagged to moderator for two aggressive rollbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But since others may be interested, I posted anyway.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String s = "12*1*145*2+8*1*1+2*3+2+4";
        List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
        // for building numbers
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        // assume there are only 2 types (number and operators)
        boolean isNumber = false;
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                if (!isNumber) {
                    builder = new StringBuilder();
                    isNumber = true;
                }
                builder.append(c);
            } else {
                if (isNumber) {
                    tokens.add(builder.toString());
                    isNumber = false;
                }
                // assume operators are exactly 1 char
                tokens.add(String.valueOf(c));
            }
        }
        if (isNumber)
            tokens.add(builder.toString());
        System.out.println(tokens);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[12, *, 1, *, 145, *, 2, +, 8, *, 1, *, 1, +, 2, *, 3, +, 2, +, 4]
```

A more general approach would use an `enum` of types to keep the current state instead of a `boolean`, and use the `builder` for all the types so that their tokens are not limited to 1 char.

Then you'll probably need to build an [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)…

Comment: Thank you very much sir. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using Regex for others:

```
String inputStr = "12*1*145*2+8*1*1+2*3+2+4";
String inputPattern = "(\\d+|[+-/*]{1})";

List<String> strList=new ArrayList<>();

Pattern patternObj = Pattern.compile(inputPattern);
Matcher matcherObj = patternObj.matcher(inputStr);


while (matcherObj.find()) {         
    strList.add(matcherObj.group(0));
}

System.out.println(strList);
```